# 'find_by' and 'where' not working with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Email field in User model is encrypted with attr_encrypted. When I create new user with devise and facebook omniauth, it's be saved in DB actually. Also, I can retrieve that data with `User.last.email #=> foo@foo.com`.

But it returns nil or [] when I use `User.find_by_email("foo@foo.com")` or `User.where(email: "foo@foo.com")`.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :email, key: Settings.encryption.key
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `attr_encrypted` gem, I think `email` is virtual field and is actually persisted in the `users` table as the `encrypted_email` field.

What does your `schema.rb` file look like for the `users` table?

If this is the case, I think you just need to use

```
User.find_by_encrypted_email("foo@foo.com")
```

instead of

```
User.find_by_email("foo@foo.com")
```

Gem documentation: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted

Good luck!